# IndentationError: expected an indented block con Python

Tags: python

Tengo poco en python y sé que es sensible a las indentaciones. He intentado colocar otro if y así, pero no me funciona. Cuando agrego más espacios o indentaciones me marca más errores.

```
print("El siguiente programa indica la estación del año dada una fecha por el usuario")

print("Ingresa el año (AAAA):")
ano = int(input())
print("Ingresa el mes (MM):")
mes = int(input())
print("Ingresa el día (DD): ")
dia = int(input())

print(ano)
print(mes)
print(dia)

if (ano>0) and (mes>0 or mes<=12) and (dia>0 or dia<=31):
elif (dia >= 20 and mes >= 3) or (dia < 20 and mes < 6):
  print("PRIMAVERA")
elif (dia >= 20 and mes >= 6) and (dia < 22 and mes < 9):
  print("VERANO")
elif (dia >= 22 and mes >= 9) and (dia < 21 and mes < 12):
  print("OTOÑO")
elif (dia >= 21 and mes >= 12) and (dia < 20 and mes < 3):
  print("INVIERNO")
elif (ano % 4 == 0 and ano % 100 != 0) or (ano % 400 == 0):
  print("AÑO BISIESTO")

else:
    print("FECHA INVALIDA")
```

Comment: ¿Es el programa nuevo o el original? ¿Dónde intentastes colocar los IF? ¿Qué significa "no funciona"?

Answer (score 1):

## Problema con el IF

Lo que te sucede, es que te falta un código, después de cada `ìf` tiene que ir un código a ejecutar en caso de que se cumpla dicha condición. Tú tienes un `if` y justo depués un `elif`. Eso no es correcto, porque tienes que decidir previamente que quieres hacer en el primer `if`.

Una vez dicho esto, si tu quieres poner un `if` y después otro segundo `ìf` que no está relacionada con la condición anterior, debes identarlo y comenzar otra vez con `if`. Tue ejemplo quedaría así en la parte que te da el error:

## Problema identación

Como bien dices, tienes otro problema con la identación. Mientras que en otros lenguajes de programación, solo se utiliza la identación para que se más legible el código, en Python la identación forma parte de su sintaxis, y sin una correcta identación el código tendrá errores.

La identación lo que hace es indicarle a Python cuales son lo **bloques de código**. Simpre que pongas un `if` debes de identar el bloque de código que se ejecutará en ese `if`. Por lo que el código quedaría así:

```
print("El siguiente programa indica la estación del año dada una fecha por el usuario")

print("Ingresa el año (AAAA):")
ano = int(input())
print("Ingresa el mes (MM):")
mes = int(input())
print("Ingresa el día (DD): ")
dia = int(input())

print(ano)
print(mes)
print(dia)

#Hacemos un primer if para verificar que introducimos una fecha valida
if (ano>0) and (mes>0 or mes<=12) and (dia>0 or dia<=31):

    #Hacemos una segunda cadena de if, para identifica la estación de la fechaa
    if (dia >= 20 and mes >= 3) or (dia < 20 and mes < 6):
        print("PRIMAVERA")
    elif (dia >= 20 and mes >= 6) and (dia < 22 and mes < 9):
        print("VERANO")
    elif (dia >= 22 and mes >= 9) and (dia < 21 and mes < 12):
        print("OTOÑO")
    elif (dia >= 21 and mes >= 12) and (dia < 20 and mes < 3):
        print("INVIERNO")

    #Este if no tiene nada que ver con el anterior, por lo que lo ejecutamos en otro bloque
    if (ano % 4 == 0 and ano % 100 != 0) or (ano % 400 == 0):
        print("AÑO BISIESTO")
    else:
        print("AÑO NO BISIESTO")

#En el caso de que las fechas no sean validas, no ejecutamos nada de lo anterior
else:
    print("FECHA INVALIDA")
```

## Por último

Sintacticamente hablando el lenguaje está bien escito, pero creo que puede guiarte a una mala comprensión del condicional `if`.

Como puedes ver he modificado la parte de **año bisiesto**, porque aunque estaba bien sintacticamente, carecia de sentido real, ya que ese bloque nunca se iba a llegar a ejecutar, porque ya habías cubierto todas las casuisticas con los anteriores `if` y `elif`. Es decir si la fecha era valida, siempre iba a entrar en alguno de los `if` anteriores a **"AÑO BISIESTO"** se iba a ejecutar e iba a romper el bucle. Por lo que nunca iba a llegar a **"AÑO BISIESTO"** (ya que todas las fechas del año pertenecen a una estación). Como que el año sea bisiesto o no, no tiene nada que ver con las estaciones, comenzamos otro bucle `if` con el nuevo tema a tratar, en este caso que sea bisiesto o no.